# How do I check to see if a Smarty variable is already assigned?

Tags: php, smarty, template-engine

How do I check to see if a particular value has already been assigned to Smarty and if not assign a (default) value?

Answer:

```
if ($this->cismarty->get_template_vars('test') === null) {
   $this->cismarty->assign('test', 'Default value');
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Smarty 2**

```
if ($smarty->get_template_vars('foo') === null) 
{
   $smarty->assign('foo', 'some value');
}
```

**Smarty 3**

```
if ($smarty->getTemplateVars('foo') === null) 
{
   $smarty->assign('foo', 'some value');
}
```

Note that for **Smarty 3**, you will have to use `$smarty->getTemplateVars` instead.

Comment: Won't that just check to see it the value is not null?  What if null is the proper assignment?

Comment: In this case the behavior should be, "if a value is not set (null) then set a default value."

Also, isset() connot be used to check the return value of a function, however you can just check the value itself.

Thanks Andy.

Comment: get_template_vars() is designed to return NULL on non-existent variables.

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct, get_template_vars will always return a valid reference so you can't check with isset()

Comment: But how about in the `.tpl` file?

Answer (score 1):

`get_template_vars()` will return null if you haven't set a variable, so you can do

```
if ($smarty->get_template_vars('test') === null) {
    echo "'test' is not assigned or is null";
}
```

However that check will fail if you have a variable assigned but set as null, in which case you could do

```
$tmp = $smarty->get_template_vars();
if (!array_key_exists('test', $tmp)) {
    echo "'test' is not assigned";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can do:

```
if (!isset($smarty['foo'])) 
{
    $smarty->assign('foo', 'some value');
}
```

Comment: This does not work with Smarty 3. You get the error `Cannot use object of type Smarty as array`